# show dialogbox is not working in `meteorJs`?

Tags: meteor

I need help for i had develop the modal dialogbox using **meteorJs** it is not working when ever click the add client button open a dialog box but it is not working please check where i did a mistake, here is my code below.

```
template:
<template name="shedule">
    <button class="btn btn-success addClients">Add Client</button>
</template>

Js code:
Session.setDefault('showclientDialog', false);
template.shedule.events({
    'button #addClient':function(e,t){

         console.log("You pressed Add Client button");
         e.preventDefault();
         Session.set('showclientDialog' , true);
    }
});
template.shedule.showclientDialog = function(){
    return Session.get('showclientDialog');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

template:

*added an if block to check the session variable*

```
<template name="shedule">
    <button class="btn btn-success addClients">Add Client</button>
    {{#if showclientDialog}}
        <div class="clientDialogue">Client Dialoge</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Js code:

*fixed the event map to check for correct selector*

```
Session.setDefault('showclientDialog', false);
Template.shedule.events({
    'click .addClients':function(e,t){

         console.log("You pressed Add Client button");
         e.preventDefault();
         Session.set('showclientDialog' , true);
    }
});

Template.shedule.showclientDialog = function(){
    return Session.get('showclientDialog');
}
```

Comment: I am modify as mentioned above but It's not working @Serkan Durusoy

Comment: what happens? do you get any errors on your browser console? there may be other parts of your code that cause additional problems.

Comment: Click event is not working and no error are came while running app @Serkan Durusoy

Comment: can you try by changing `template` to `Template`

Comment: Thank you for giving suggestion but in events js code in place button i am writing click it is working once again thank you. @Serkan Durusoy

Comment: Ah yes! definitely, I've not noticed that. Fixed it.